# How to get the data appended through SVG root

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working on SVG with javascript, i want to know how to get the data, which is append by the SVG root, from where i can access that all data, any help will be awesome. Thnxs Reagards:
Zain

Comment: Same question by the same user: [Accessing the SVG data through JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201782/accessing-the-svg-data-through-javascript); that question has been answered, please close and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried document.getElementById("yourNode");? This should work pretty much the same like in HTML, whether it's a standalone SVG or if you're mixing SVG with XHTML.